# Scaleproblem: VizFrame Dual Barchart Rendering of Values

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I made a dual barchart with vizframe, but I ran into a problem.

The values of the two datasets don't render on the same scale.

This makes the comparison of the datasets near impossible.

Example:
[show problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj6dk.png)

Example: [plnkr.co/edit/0O4gATp0P5ZvYoof](https://plnkr.co/edit/0O4gATp0P5ZvYoof)

Solution: https://plnkr.co/edit/9ziljXNgOPR7jiA3?preview

[Problem in example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1voNP.png)

Is it possible in VizFrame to force the two datasets to render on the one with the highest value or should I use another type of chart?

View:

```
<layout:FixFlex id='fixchart' minFlexSize="1000">
                        <layout:flexContent>
                            <viz:VizFrame id="idVizFrame" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}" height='100%' width="100%" vizType='dual_bar'>
                                <viz:dataset>
                                    <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{ path : '/ZSD_INVOICE_DIF' , sorter : { path: 'sales_org_text'}}">
                                        <viz.data:dimensions>
                                            <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Verkaufsorganisationen" value="{sales_org_text}" />
                                        </viz.data:dimensions>
                                        <viz.data:measures>
                                            <viz.data:MeasureDefinition group="1" name="letztes Jahr" value="{amount_last_year}" />
                                            <viz.data:MeasureDefinition group="2" name="aktuelles Jahr" value="{amount_this_year}" />
                                        </viz.data:measures>
                                    </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
                                </viz:dataset>
                                <viz:feeds>
                                    <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension" values="Verkaufsorganisationen" />
                                    <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='valueAxisFeed' uid="valueAxis" type="Measure" values="letztes Jahr" />
                                    <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='valueAxisFeed2' uid="valueAxis2" type="Measure" values="aktuelles Jahr" />
                                </viz:feeds>
                            </viz:VizFrame>
                        </layout:flexContent>
                    </layout:FixFlex>
```

Comment: Can you show (in an image) what you want to achieve? From your wording it's not clear to me what the problem and expected result is..

Comment: @Marc  You can see the problem if you click(show problem) on the link. I cant show images any other way because its my first question. In the picture you can see that the bar of 5k is much longer than the bar of 300k. What I want to achieve is to put the two values in relation and make the differents visable for the user. 
I hope this helps.
If you need more information, just let me know!

Comment: Would be easiest if you showed a small sample app on plnkr where the problem is reproducible. Because If I look at the SAP samples there are plenty of charts with two series. So I guess there is a problem with your feeds/measures/data/binding and that's hard to debug by seeing 10 lines of XML.

Comment: @Marc https://plnkr.co/edit/0O4gATp0P5ZvYoof
you can see the probelm with vkorg22 and vkorg222

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me: https://i.imgur.com/DZ4G4gF.png

Comment: @Marc it seems to be on your screen. 
I will attach a screenshot of my screen to the post.

Comment: Can you clear your browser cache? If it's working perfectly fine in my browser and not in yours then maybe you are the problem ;)

Comment: I did and tried different browsers. It didnt work, but I found something interessting!
Depending on the size of the window it renders diffrently.
If I have the window on around 1/3 of the screen it renders wrong, but if I extend the window to 1/2 of the screen it renders right.
It renders wrong from 746x565 to 624x630.
The wrong render room seems to differ depending on the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in Viz.

It will render wrong depending on the size of the window and the values of the dataset.
I checked it with different browsers and different PCs.
A workaround would be to set the max values of the axis.

A solution was found! I will at the code solution to the question.

It needs to be reduced to one value axis and the barchart needs to be normal bar chart!

Comment: Please get in touch with the [product support](https://support.sap.com/en/my-support/product-support.html) and possibly create a customer incident when finding a bug in SAPUI5 classes. If you feel the bug is rather in OpenUI5, create an issue at https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann I will if Im sure, it is still possible that I have faulty code. 
I will post any development.